# Why does AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', ()=>App) works even though App is already a function returning a component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

If I understand correctly, registerComponent expects a function returning a component as its second argument, as in my first try below.

Since App is such a function, I would have expected it to work as is, and I don't understand why I need to pass ()=>App instead (Passing App directly results in the error below).

index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {App} from './src/App';
import {Test} from './src/App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => Test); // option 1, works
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', App); // option 2, doesn't work, error below
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App); // option 3, works
```

./src/App.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Text,  View} from 'react-native';
export class Test extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View><Text>Foo</Text></View>
    );
  }
}

export const App= () =>(
    <Test/>
);
```

> ExceptionsManager.js:73 Check your code at renderApplication.js:35.
>
> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>      built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>      but got: object. ExceptionsManager.js:65
>
> This error is located at:
>
> ```js
> in RCTView (at View.js:71)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
> in RCTView (at View.js:71)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App is executed and `<Test />` is returned. Though Test is a function or class, but `<Test />` is an object, the result of `React.createElement`. That is the reason why the second option is failing.

We need a function that returns a function / class, not a function that returns an object.